# WPF "Insert" control per binding

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding

I have a `UserControl` without `Content`, because the control which should be shown inside of the UserControl is created at runtime. I would like to solve this like follows, but don't know how to implement it:

1. Create a Control-variable in the `ViewModel`
2. Set it at runtime when the content is created
3. Bind a content property (inside the UserControl) to that variable

The problem is, that I don't know how to bind to the control-variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why just not to use `ContentControl` instead of `UserControl` and provide `Content` in runtime by introducing a `DataTemplateSelector` which able to provide right `DataTemplate` in runtime?
You can encapsulate your Content-area controls in `DataTemplates` and select appropriate one in runtime.

Comment: if you need any advices feel free to ask here